# Execute multiple insert statements as batch in SQLDeveloper

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a script which has around 2600 insert statements on a single table. Like below

```
insert into STUDENT(NAME, ROLL) VALUES('Bob', 1);
insert into STUDENT(NAME, ROLL) VALUES('Ron', 2);
.
.
insert into STUDENT(NAME, ROLL) VALUES('Jack', 2600);
```

I am running this script (Oracle DB) by pressing `F9` and it starts executing line by line and takes lot of time.

Is there a way I can execute them all at once?

NOTE: The insert script is generated through export and I cannot change it in the below format

```
insert into STUDENT
VALUES
('Bob', 1),
('Ron', 2),
.
.
('Jack', 2600);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script contains separate `INSERT INTO` statements and they are executed as such - separately, one-by-one.

If you exported data into an e.g. CSV file, you could have

- used SQL*Loader or
- external tables feature

to do it much faster. But, as you didn't, let the script run and wait a while. I don't think that you have any other option (unless you separate it into several smaller files and run them in separate SQL*Plus connections in parallel, but that would probably take more time to prepare than wait for current script to finish).

---

As of SQL*Loader:

- first, make sure you have data in a textual file (separated by e.g. semi-colon)
- check whether you have SQL*Loader on your computer. It is installed along with any Oracle database or - if you don't have it on your PC - Oracle Client software
- then create a control file which uses the CSV file as input and loads data into appropriate columns in the target table

This is [Oracle 11g SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_ldr.htm) documentation. It takes time to read it but - regarding the fact that it is a simple two-column table, should be fairly simple to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me how can I export data using SQLDeveloper using SQL*Loader format? So that I have it all in a single insert statement

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: Is there any other way, using which I can directly export data in the single insert query format using SQL Developer only? It is a bigger table, I have just made it simpler so that it is easier to ask here....

Comment: you could use data pump as well

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am more specifically looking to keep backup of insert statements and then execute them elsewhere based on need. I infer from this that I cannot execute the queries in a faster way unless I find a way to export sql queries in a single insert statement.

Comment: If you move data around frequently, read about export and import utilities (either "original" EXP/IMP or Data Pump). They are designed for such a purpose and work *fast*. Option you chose is probably the slowest.